# templavoila image filed not shown in typo3

Tags: templates, typo3, templavoila

In my templavoila I have an image field. It's mapped to be put inside a div tag.

[image]

Then I add an image to my page:

[image]

But when the page is rendered I get this HTML:

```
<img width="" height="" border="0" alt="" src="">
```

Any ideas why the src attribute does not get filled?

Comment: As there is no thumbnail generated as well, did you check the image magick settings in the install tool? Do the test images get generated correctly there?

Comment: Thanks ImageMagic was missing. I wasn't aware that it does not come with XAMPP. But it can easily be downloaded and installed from the main ImageMagic website.

Comment: Feal free to add this as answer in order i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no thumbnail generated as well your image magick settings are probably wrong.
Do the test images get generated correctly there? If not, maybe an update of your [binary](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) solves it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the mapping is wrong. you can try this:

[image: tv mapping]